# What is the best way to make a train route application with Spring Boot and Azure?

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot

My question here is my own follow up of a school project. We implemented a basic train system with 15 cities and when the user inputed 2 cities (aka current location and destination) the app returned the quickest way from A to B as well as the cheapest. We ran A Star algorithms for this.
My question here is: If i wanted to implement this with Spring Boot and Azure how would i do it? I assume MySQL for pathfinding could be bad in performance or even just impossible to simulate a graph. We used guava graph (extended versions) for the "vanilla" app, but how would i do it in a real world environment? How would i be able to run a star searches? I've heared about Cosmos Gremlin and there is a Spring Boot starter and all, but would this be possible? If so how, or even if its reasonably doable with MySQL, how?
Thanks in advance